# Converting Proteus PCB to Altium PCB file

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, altium, proteus, pcb-layers

Hey all I am converting a Proteus PCB design into Altium and I am wondering what each file is since it asks me in Altium.

My Proteus files are:

[image]

And this is what Altium does when I do a **PCB Design Check/Fix**:

[image]

And so I say *Yes* and I am presented with this:

[image]

And this is where I am not sure what to put for each... Any help would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that those are Gerber photoplot files.

Looking at some of the types listed, I'd say cadacam-bottom-silkscreen.txt should be "Silk Bot", ...bottom_solder_resist.txt should be "Mask Bot".  Others seem pretty obvious, although you may have a bit of a problem guessing at the valid type names.

The file names seem to me to be self-explanatory, if you have some idea of the photoplot files required to make a PC board.

Comment: What would these be?
**cadcam_mechanical_1.txt** and 
**cadcam_top_copper.txt**

Comment: since _bottom_copper.txt is Bottom, I'd expect _top_copper.txt to be Top.  That is, those two layers are the top and bottom copper patterns (pads and tracks) for your board. _mechanical_1.txt may be the board outline - you'd have to view that file to be sure.  The silk_screen files will be the text printed on the finished board.  _solder_resist is often called solder mask - it is the green coating that covers the board, except where you want to apply solder.

Comment: I updated my OP to show whats inside the cadcam_mechanical_1 file.

Comment: The cadcam_mechanical_1 file looks like a Gerber photoplot file.  You should look at it (and all the other files) with a Gerber file viewer.  If I remember correctly, a Gerber viewer was included with Altium.  If you can't find it, google for "Gerber file viewer" - there are a couple of free ones available.

Comment: It seems to just be a blank square with an outer outline.

Comment: Well, yes - didn't I say mechanical_1 was probably the board outline?  In the Gerber viewer, you should be able to view all the Geber files superimposed, to show the full board.